# Cannot use sass in WebStorm as file watcher due to cache, despite setting --no-cache in args

Tags: sass, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to set up WebStorm to use sass.

I point the watcher at my sass file and specify `--no-cache` in the arguments yet I still get this error when trying to compile sass:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.js --no-cache --update main.scss:main.css
Could not find an option named "cache".

Usage: sass <input.scss> [output.css]
       sass <input.scss>:<output.css> <input/>:<output/> <dir/>
```

I have seen other questions regarding this error but all say to add the `--no-cache` arg to the watcher but this does not work.

[image]

How do I disable the cache when `--no-cache` doesn't work?

Comment: Run your `sass` compiler in terminal with `--help` to see all available options and the name of your compiler. I bet it will not have `--no-cache` option listed there. AFAIK this option is available for the original (now outdated) [Ruby-based compiler](https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass) while [node-saas](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) (that I'm still using) has no such option and has completely different parameters anyway.

Comment: In short: extremely likely you are using the wrong syntax / parameters for your Sass compiler.